# Set timelines in embedded youtube video in my own website

Tags: php, wordpress, web, video, youtube

I have embedded youtube video in my website and timelines in text format. Is there a way to make my text timelines clickable for user to jump between timelines in embedded video, similar to how it's working in youtube?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this plugin for wordpress can help you :
https://wordpress.org/plugins/skip-to-timestamp/

Otherwise you can add **?start=[nbSeconds]** to the embed url like so :

```
https://www.youtube.com/embed/bESGLojNYSo?start=50
```

and modify the player url with some javascript when clicking on the timeline link